# Text that continues in next line when it reaches the end of the form C# (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, text, cmd

So i want to make a WinForm app that will start typing text from the upper left corner all the way to the lower right corner like a console application, when it reaches the end of a line it continues in a new line.

eg:

```
>line 1:     I need y
>
>line 2:     our help
```

The text should be chopped, if you get what i mean.

Comment: dock a richtextbox, and look on google for a wrap text setting (I think it does by default)

Comment: What do you mean by `chopped`? Any example? I think wrapping the text is OK, for example, if the text is `Long text` can't be written in a line, the word `text` may be written at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: What he means is that the text should ignore wrapping on a word boundary. When you turn wrapping on for TextBox and RichText, it smartly wraps to keep words together. The OP just wants it to wrap at the max line length even if it is in the middle of a word.

Comment: Creating your own TextBox or RichTextBox control is a *lot* harder than it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MultiLine Textbox .. you have to notice that

[1] Will be easier if you use fix width fonts .. this the idea (not real code)

```
charlimit = me.width / textwidth("A") ----> use graph textrender function here
```

[2] You can control **textbox_textchanged** event to ensure that the word not get '**autowrap**' to next line .. so when the text position is in most right position you can chop it by add the text with **vbCrLf** ..

```
if LastLine.Length = charlimit then

     alltext += vbCrLf

     lastLine = ""

endif
```

But this would be hard when you do in middle row because you have to reccount the words after it (below it) ..

Comment: That`s a great idea but, how can I check if the text has reached that point?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RichTextBox` for this purpose. It represents a rich text control that supports formatted text, hyperlinks, inline images, and other rich content.

`RichTextBox.TextWrapping` Property of `RichTextBox` can help you.

- It gets or sets how text wrapping occurs if a line of text extends beyond the available width of the `RichTextBox`.
- You should consider the width of the `RichTextBox` when you set the `TextWrapping` property.
- Any text that extends beyond the bounds of the RichTextBox will not be displayed. If the `TextWrapping` property is set to `NoWrap`, text that exceeds the horizontal bounds can be scrolled into view using the cursor. Text that exceeds vertically can be scrolled into view using the keyboard or scrollbar.
- If the `TextWrapping` property is set to Wrap, the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property is automatically set to Disabled and any property changes to the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need the text to be chopped.